What is this usage of つく?
緑をかき分ける。巣を割られた羽虫たちが苛んで追ってくる。自分は必死に斜面を駆けた。前のめりに、けれど膝だけはつかないように、
The character is running through jungle and his narration says this. i get what the sentence is saying but what to make of けれど膝だけはつかないように、?
I understand it's "so only my knees don't" but what is the actual verb?

The base form of the verb is 膝{ひざ}を突{つ}く, which means to "stumble and fall to one's knees".
Your sentence is

膝だけはつかないように、[...]

This means that the narrator is doing something ([...]) to prevent his knees from touching the ground (falling over).
